# Failed to load url /admin/polyfills.js (resolved id: /admin/polyfills.js). Does the file exist?” Angular 17 route with the path /admin/xxxx

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, angular17

I’m working on an Angular 17 application and I’m trying to create a route with the path /admin/xxxx.
However, when I try to access the route http://localhost:4200/admin/dashboard, I get the following error:
[image]

20:44:30 [vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to load url /admin/polyfills.js (resolved id: /admin/polyfills.js). Does the file exist?
20:44:30 [vite] Pre-transform error: Failed to load url /admin/main.js (resolved id: /admin/main.js). Does the file exist?

Here’s what my code looks like:
ps : when i use path : '' it works fine with routes http://localhost:4200/dashboard

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    // canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    // canActivateChild: [AdminGuard],
    component: LayoutComponent,
    data: {
      layout: 'admin',
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./modules/users/users.module').then((m) => m.UsersModule),
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(
            (m) => m.DashboardModule
          ),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
```

Can anyone help me figure out what’s causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you check your `base href` in your `index.html`

Comment: Check your angular.json and look for `polyfills` in projects-->your-app-->architect-->build-->options. If you neend't polyfill, remove the line. Generally you use polyfill to import 'zone.js' (but you can import in anyplace diferent) or '@angular/localize/init';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and find a solution here

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26897

It is an issue that was corrected in the code, but I updated all my package and still have the problem.

In the url someone suggest to use `"externalDependencies":[""]`, in the options of the angular.json like this:

```
angular.json 
"build": {
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
"options": {
"externalDependencies":[""],
```

and it worked to me. I hope it can help, and I suggest to visit the url.

Comment: Do you know the work around for monorepo projects? It doesn't have angular.json. It has project.json

Comment: Sorry, I don´t. I find the solution in the URI shared. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I figured that out. The solution for project.json is very similar to angular.json. But it doesn't solve the problem completely. There are still a lot of vitejs requests